# Java get substring from HTML URL

Tags: java

I have a string:

```
<img src="https://google.com">
```

I would like to extract https://google.com from this this, ie, the substring after the last " or first " from right.

Could someone please provide some help?

I could not input " " " into the line below,it keep give me error.

```
line.lastIndexOf(""")
```

Comment: `line.lastIndexOf("\"");`

Comment: Learn about [escaping special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: oh my god , thanks i totally forgotten...been a while since i touch programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line.lastIndexOf(""")` gives an error because the compiler cannot differentiate between the 3 `"` and when matches 2 of them to form a pair, the 3rd one remains unmatched.

Use an escape character `\`. So `line.lastIndexOf("\"");` will do what you intend to do, get the index of the last occurence of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape it (the double quote) with backslash.

```
line.lastIndexOf("\"");
```